# Is there a way to search text files matching keywords instead of full names?

Tags: python

I am building a machine learning bot with a very simple database idea, creating text files for each question and i want to be able to find some answers based on similarity of keywords.

A text file name might be `hello,world,good.txt`. Is there a way to locate that using the keywords `world` and `good` in a sentence the user inputs in python?

I have coded

```
try:
    with open(tokens, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        answer = random.choice(lines[1:])
        print(answer)
except FileNotFoundError:
        create_file = open(tokens, 'w')
        create_file.close()
        opened_file = open(tokens, 'a')
        opened_file.write("%s\n" %user_input)
        opened_file.close()
except IndexError:
```

If all else fails and it gets here it should break down the tokens variable into keywords (the keywords in tokens are already separated by commas and find a text file based on that)'''

Example of a `tokens` variable: `'Key,Lock,Door'`

Answer (score 1):

If you are specificly using an Unix os, you can use the find function from

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["find .", "-name="*pattern*.txt"])
```

Or the clean solution : use regular expressions. Their whole point is to handle this kind of issue!
Have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)

You can read all the files from the directory 'tokens' and use regex to filter